# how to get value from a datakey field inside datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a datalist and i set DataKeyField

```
 <asp:DataList ID="lstItems" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"  DataKeyField="itemid" >
  <ItemTemplate>
  //contents in the datalist here
  </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:DataList>
```

i also have a imagebutton say imgADD in the page.My question is how can i get the value of datakey in imgADD click on server side

Comment: Client-side click or server-side click?

Comment: Is that button outside of the Datalist or inside it ?

Answer (score 4):

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList_projects" runat="server" RepeatColumns="1" DataKeyNames="ID"
         RepeatDirection="Horizontal" onitemcommand="DataList_projects_ItemCommand" >

        <HeaderStyle ForeColor="Red" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        <hr style="color:" />
     <asp:Label ID="ltlproject" ForeColor="#cc0000"  runat="server" text="PROJECT:"></asp:Label>  &nbsp;<b><u><asp:Label ID="lblProject" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TITLE")%>' ></asp:Label></u></b> &nbsp;  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" ForeColor="Red"  CommandName="Edit" runat="server">Edit</asp:LinkButton><br />


    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

in your code behind

```
protected void DataList_projects_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
        {

           string strId = DataList_projects.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex].ToString();

        }

    }
```

i think this will help you....

Answer (score 0):

### **ASPX code:**

```
//In the DataList ItemTemplate: 
.. 
.. 
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgADD" runat="server" ImageUrl="uri" ToolTip="Add" 
CommandName="Add" />
```

### **Code-behind:**

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, 
DataListCommandEventArgs e) 
{ 
  if(e.CommandName == "Add") 
  { 
    string keyID; 

    // Get the index of the row from which this event was raised. 
    int idx = e.Item.ItemIndex; 

    // Get the DataKey with the same index. 
    object thisKey = DataList1.DataKeys(idx); 
    if(thisKey != null) 
    { 
      keyID = thisKey.ToString(); 
      // do something here 
    } 
 }
```

}